# Combining CASE Statements via SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am trying to merge the below queries used for separate reports by combining the `CASE` statements. The `JOIN` information is the same, but the result of the `WHERE` statements also differs. For the `Case_Type_ID`, I need all records that are equal to both `1` and `2`.

The queries are as follows:

Query 1:

```
SELECT
, XXXX
, (CASE WHEN question3.option_id = 3 THEN 'Symptomatic' ELSE CASE WHEN question3.option_id = 4 THEN 'Asymptomatic' ELSE NULL END END) AS SYMPTOM_STATUS

WHERE crr.case_Type_Id = 1 
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN question3.option_id = 3 THEN 'Symptomatic' ELSE CASE WHEN question3.option_id = 4 THEN 'Asymptomatic' ELSE NULL END END)
ORDER BY crr.QUARANTINE_END_DATE DESC
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT
, XXX
, (CASE WHEN question3.option_id = 17 THEN 'Symptomatic' ELSE CASE WHEN question3.option_id = 18 THEN 'Asymptomatic' ELSE NULL END END) AS SYMPTOM_STATUS

WHERE crr.case_Type_Id = 2 
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN question3.option_id = 17 THEN 'Symptomatic' ELSE CASE WHEN question3.option_id = 18 THEN
'Asymptomatic' ELSE NULL END END)
ORDER BY crr.QUARANTINE_END_DATE DESC"
```

Comment: `case` _expressions_, not statements. However, your queries look very odd. Simplify - [mcve], to make it easier to assist you.

Comment: BTW, which dbms are you using? (The above syntax is product specific.)

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL Developer. The queries have been reduced to minimize space and overall code being displayed. The JOINs that were created are exactly the same. The remainder of the fields missing from the SELECT statement are excluded for the purposes of space.

Comment: Reducing space here became making it very strange. If you remove a column from the select clause, also remove it from the group by clause. A query is expected to be consistent and making sense.

Comment: Edited to reduce confusion. Thank you for your input.

Comment: It looks like you want `case` _expressions_ to do _conditional aggregation_. (I.e. have one query, OR the WHERE clause conditions, use case expressions.)

Comment: Are you a student, or a professional in the database field? I ask because someone wanted to know your dbms and you answered "SQL Developer". To understand your answer, it would help to know what you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any other thing in your simplified code let's focus on your CASE expressions and the title of the question:
**Your CASE**

```sql
(CASE WHEN question3.option_id = 3 THEN 'Symptomatic' ELSE CASE WHEN question3.option_id = 4 THEN 'Asymptomatic' ELSE NULL END END) AS SYMPTOM_STATUS
```

If you put it this way (much more readable)

```sql
    (CASE 
        WHEN question3.option_id = 3 THEN 'Symptomatic' 
    ELSE 
        CASE 
            WHEN question3.option_id = 4 THEN 'Asymptomatic' 
        ELSE NULL 
        END 
    END) as SYMPTOM_STATUS
```

It is exactly the same but now it is ease to see that it could be written as one CASE expression with two WHEN conditions and make it a bit more simple. CASE expresions them selves does not need bracets to function as they already have strict sintax with CASE at start and END on the other side. So it could be like this:

```sql
    CASE 
        WHEN question3.option_id = 3 THEN 'Symptomatic' 
        WHEN question3.option_id = 4 THEN 'Asymptomatic' 
    ELSE 
        NULL 
    END as SYMPTOM_STATUS
```

Furthermore, if none of WHEN conditions is satisfied CASE will return Null, so in this example ELSE could be ommited:

```sql
    CASE 
        WHEN question3.option_id = 3 THEN 'Symptomatic' 
        WHEN question3.option_id = 4 THEN 'Asymptomatic' 
    END as SYMPTOM_STATUS
```

It looks ok now, simple and readable. The same thing done with your 2nd CASE expression would look like this:

```sql
    CASE 
        WHEN question3.option_id = 17 THEN 'Symptomatic' 
        WHEN question3.option_id = 18 THEN 'Asymptomatic' 
    END as SYMPTOM_STATUS
```

If you combine it with the previous one it says that if option_id is 3 or 17 then 'Symptomatic' and if 4 or 18 then Asymptomatic. Let's try to put it like this:

```sql
    CASE 
        WHEN question3.option_id = 3 OR question3.option_id = 17 THEN 'Symptomatic' 
        WHEN question3.option_id = 4 OR question3.option_id = 18 THEN 'Asymptomatic' 
    END as SYMPTOM_STATUS
```

Now you have them both combined and in one CASE expression with two WHEN conditions. This one should do the job as it is expected to. But (in this example data) it could be even more simplified if we put it like this:

```sql
    CASE 
        WHEN question3.option_id IN(3, 17) THEN 'Symptomatic' 
        WHEN question3.option_id IN(4, 18) THEN 'Asymptomatic' 
    END as SYMPTOM_STATUS
```

And that's it. If option_id is 3 or 17 the returned value is 'Symptomatic', if option_id is either 4 or 18 then 'Asymptomatic' and any other value of option_id will return Null.
Regards...

Comment: Thank you so much. The last part is exactly what I was missing..